# Rewriting the equation $m\dfrac{d^2\vec{r}(t)}{dt^2} = \vec{F}(\vec{r}(t))$ as a differential equation of order 1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following equation: $m\dfrac{d^2\vec{r}(t)}{dt^2} = \vec{F}(\vec{r}(t))$.

I am asked to rewrite it into a differential equation of order 1.

I guesd I'd have to simplify the equation $\int m\dfrac{d^2\vec{r}(t)}{dt^2}dt = \int \vec{F}(\vec{r}(t))dt$

But I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Can you assume that there is a function $f$ with $\vec F = \nabla f$?

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the equation by $\frac{d \vec{r(t)}}{dt}$ on both sides and then you can use

$\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{d \vec{r(t)}}{dt}^2) = 2 \frac{d \vec{r(t)}}{dt} \frac{d^2 \vec{r(t)}}{dt^2}$.

Finally, integrate by time $dt$.

Answer (score 0):

The Newton's law is
$$m\ddot{r}+\nabla{V}(r)=0$$
Multiply by $\dot{r}$ you get $$m\ddot{r}\dot{r}+\nabla{V}(r)\dot{r}=\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{m}{2}\dot{r}^{2}+V(r))=0$$
Hence
$$\frac{m}{2}\dot{r}^{2}+V(r)=E$$
If $V(r, t)$ is explicilty time dependent, then
$$m\ddot{r}+\nabla{V}(r, t)=0$$
Multiply by $\dot{r}$ you get $$m\ddot{r}\dot{r}+\nabla{V}(r, t)\dot{r}=\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{m}{2}\dot{r}^{2}+V(r, t))-\frac{\partial{V}(r, t)}{\partial{t}}=0$$
Hence
$$\frac{dE}{dt}=\frac{\partial{V}(r, t)}{\partial{t}}$$